# how to use solve_ivp solve Partial Differential Equations with spectral method?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical-methods, pde

I want to use the spectral method to solve partial differential equations. The equations like that, [formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDAgk.png),the initial condition is u(t=0,x)=(a^2)*sech(x),u'_t (t=0)=0.

To solve it, I use the python with the spectral method. Following is the code,

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
from scipy.fftpack import diff as psdiff

#RHS of equations
def f(t,u):
    uxx= psdiff(u[N:],period=L,order=2)
    du1dt=u[:N]
    du2dt =a**2*uxx
    dudt=np.append(du1dt,du2dt)
    return dudt

a=1
amin=-40;bmax=40
L=bmax-amin;N=256
deltax=L/N
x=np.arange(amin,bmax,deltax)

u01 = 2*np.cosh(x)**(-1)
u02=np.zeros(N)
# y0
inital=np.append(u01,u02)

sola1 = solve_ivp(f, t_span=[0,40],y0=inital,args=(a,))

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,sola1.y[:N,5])
plt.show()
```

Following is my expected result,

[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHwm4.png).

My python code can run,but I can't get the expected result,and can't find the problem.Following is the result from my python code,
[my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YodoR.png)

-----------------------------Update----------------------------------------------
I also try a new code,but still can't solve

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.fftpack import diff as psdiff
from itertools import chain 
def lambdifide_odes(y,t,a):
    # uxx =- (1j)**2*k**2*u[:N]
    u1=y[::2]
    u2=y[1::2]
    dudt=np.empty_like(y)
    du1dt=dudt[::2]
    du2dt=dudt[1::2]

    du1dt=u2
    uxx=psdiff(u1,order=2,period=L)
    du2dt=a**2*uxx
    return dudt
a=1
amin=-40;bmax=40
L=bmax-amin;N=256
deltax=L/N
x=np.arange(amin,bmax,deltax)
u01 = 2*np.cosh(x)**(-1)
u02=np.zeros(N)
initial=np.array(list(chain.from_iterable(zip(u01,u02))))
t0=np.linspace(0,40,100)
sola1 = odeint(lambdifide_odes,y0=initial,t=t0,args=(a,))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,sola1[20,::2])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some slight problem with the design of your state vector and using this in the ODE function. The overall intent is that `u[:N]` is the wave function and `u[N:]` its time derivative. Now you want the second space derivative of the wave function, thus you need to use

```
uxx= psdiff(u[:N],period=L,order=2)
```

at the moment you use the time derivative, making this a mixed third derivative that does not occur in the equation.

Comment: Very thank you for your comment. I corrected my code the same as what you said, but can't get an expected result. maybe my code about the plot has some problems? Could you give me more hint?

Answer (score 0):

You got `uxx` calculated out of `u[N:]` instead of `u[N:]`. `du1dt` should be equal to `u[:N]` instead of `u[N:]`. I also changed the formula to calculate the second derivative of `u`. I matched the results you provided. Following is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pde_def = r'$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t}=a^2\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}$' + '\n' + r'$u(t=0, x) = a^2 sech(x)$' + '\n' + r'$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}_{(t=0)} = 0$'
        
#RHS of equations
def f(t, u, a, deltax):
    N = len(u) // 2
    uxx = np.gradient(np.gradient(u[:N], deltax), deltax)
    du1dt=u[N:]
    du2dt =a**2 * uxx
    dudt=np.append(du1dt, du2dt)
    return dudt

a=1
amin=-40; bmax=40
N=1000
assert N % 2 == 0
deltax = (bmax - amin) / (N - 1)
x = np.linspace(amin, bmax, N)
t_eval = [0, 5, 10, 20]

u01 = 2*np.cosh(x)**(-1)
u02 = np.zeros(N)
# y0
inital=np.append(u01, u02)

sola1 = solve_ivp(f, t_span=[0, 40], t_eval=t_eval, y0=inital, args=(a, deltax))

for i in range(len(sola1.t)):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 4))
    ax.plot(x,sola1.y[:N, i])
    plt.title(f'{pde_def}\na = {a}\nSolution at t = {sola1.t[i]}', fontsize=30)
    plt.ylim([0, 2])
```